# Sorting NSArray and returning NSArray?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am just looking at sorting an `NSArray` of `NSNumbers` into numeric order but am a little unsure of the best way to go. By my way of thinking 001 and 002 are pretty comparable, so I would suspect either will do. For 003 I am not sure if returning `NSMutableArray` when the method expects `NSArray` is good practice, it works, but it feels awkward.

```
-(NSArray *)testMethod:(NSArray *)arrayNumbers {    
    // 001
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayNumbers];
    [sortedArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    arrayNumbers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:sortedArray];
    return(arrayNumbers);   
}
```

.

```
-(NSArray *)testMethod:(NSArray *)arrayNumbers {    
    // 002
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayNumbers];
    [sortedArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    arrayNumbers = [[sortedArray copy] autorelease];
    return(arrayNumbers);   
}
```

.

```
-(NSArray *)testMethod:(NSArray *)arrayNumbers {    
    // 003
    NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arrayNumbers];
    [sortedArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    return(sortedArray);    
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need a mutable array at all. You can just do:

```
NSArray* sortedArray = [arrayNumbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Thank you Jason, totally missed that one, much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I think you can just call

```
return [arrayNumbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

NSArray* sortedArray = [arrayNumbers sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];