# copy and sort an NSArray in one step

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, sorting, nsarray

I am trying to sort an NSArray.
Unfortunately the array appears to stay empty.
I start with an NSMutableArray with normal distributed data called "gaussianPopulation" which is then to be copied and sorted into the NSArray "sortedData".

I checked a similar post here: [Sorting NSArray and returning NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553894/sorting-nsarray-and-returning-nsarray)

But I am still missing something...

Population.h:

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX 0x100000000

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Population : NSObject

@property NSMutableArray *totalPopulation;
@property NSMutableArray *gaussianPopulation;

-(void)createPopulation;          // test purpose to create uniform distribution. not used anymore.
-(void)createGaussianPopulation;
-(double)calculateAndersonDarling;

@end
```

and Population.m:

```
#import "Population.h"

#include <math.h>

@implementation Population

-(void)createPopulation
{
    _totalPopulation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    srandom((int)time(NULL));

    NSNumber *randomNumber;

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000 ; i++)
         {
             randomNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithInt:random()];
             [_totalPopulation addObject:randomNumber];

             NSLog(@"%@", randomNumber);

         }
}


-(void)createGaussianPopulation
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5000 ; i++)
    {
        double x1, x2, w, y1, y2;

        do
        {

            x1 = 2.0 * ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) - 1.0;
            x2 = 2.0 * ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) - 1.0;
            w = x1  * x1 + x2 * x2;
        } while (w >= 1.0);

        w = sqrt((-2.0 * log(w))/w);
        y1 = x1 * w;
        y2 = x2 * w;

        NSNumber *value1 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:y1];
        NSNumber *value2 = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:y2];



        [self.gaussianPopulation addObject:value1];
        [self.gaussianPopulation addObject:value2];

        //NSLog(@"%@    %@", value1, value2);

        NSString *pathToDesktop = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/%@/Desktop", NSUserName()];

        //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/testfile.tst", pathToDesktop];

        //create content
        NSString *content = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@ \n", [value1 stringValue], [value2 stringValue]];

        NSFileHandle *myHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:fileName];
        [myHandle seekToEndOfFile];
        [myHandle writeData:[content dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

}

-(double)calculateAndersonDarling
{

    NSLog((@"in method calculateAndersonDarling"));

    NSLog(@"%i", [self.gaussianPopulation count]);
    for (id eachObject in self.gaussianPopulation)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", eachObject);
    }



    NSArray *sortedData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.gaussianPopulation sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]];


    //NSArray *sortedData = [self.gaussianPopulation sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];


    NSLog(@"%i", [sortedData count]);

    for (id eachObject in sortedData)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", eachObject);
    }


    return 0.0; //return value to be done later

}

@end
```

As you can see (where the commented line is) I have tried different approaches.
But it seems like the sortedData array remains empty.
The size via NSLog is reported as zero and there is no output for the contents.

Any help would be appreciated.

just in case:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "Population.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {

        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        Population *myPopulation;
        myPopulation = [[Population alloc] init];
        [myPopulation createGaussianPopulation];
        [myPopulation calculateAndersonDarling];




    }
    return 0;
}
```

NSLog output:

```
2014-09-12 16:46:44.647 Statistik[4158:303] Hello, World!
2014-09-12 16:46:45.154 Statistik[4158:303] in method calculateAndersonDarling
2014-09-12 16:46:45.154 Statistik[4158:303] 0
2014-09-12 16:46:45.155 Statistik[4158:303] 0
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

clearly the Array gaussianPopulation is already empty in the method calculateAndersonDarling, or is my calculation of the array size wrong?
But why should it have lost its contents???

Comment: Could you show a few value in `gaussianPopulation`?

Comment: Also log the contents in self.gaussianPopulation before the sorting line. Also what kind of objects do you have in it? Are they NSNumbers or some other kind of object?

Comment: And the compare: method as well?

Comment: Kaan: good hint... gaussianPopulation it is also empty already within this method.... so there is nothing to copy from....

Comment: What about the property? How is it synthetized? Have you tried using [self.gaussianPopulation addObject:value1]; instead of [_gaussianPopulation addObject:value1];  ?

Comment: Bedford: I have tried just now. all the same. should be just a different way to access a property, right? so i would not have expected a different outcome...

Comment: I thought maybe it was synthetized in a different way. But it's not the case appearently. Could you post the rest of the code from the class (if it's self contained and not confidential), so that some of us might check/debug it?

Comment: of course... it is just a hobby project... :-) nothing secret about it at all... give me 2 minutes and maybe throw out some things, that would only cause confusion....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to allocate the gaussianPopulation array before adding elements to it. In Objective-C you can call methods on nil objects, it won't have any effect (no crash, no warning). That's why it's sometimes difficult to see these bugs. Just initialize the array at the beginning of the method:

```
- (void)createGaussianPopulation
{
    self.gaussianPopulation = [NSMutableArray array];
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You are absolutely right. Good to know, I guess c++ would not have compiled or at least crashed when I added elements. And of course it was not the right way to NSLog() the strings instead of the contents of the array.